# How do I add a conditional ie 6,7,and 8 stylesheet to my feature?

Tags: 7, features

Where and what code do I need to add to include a conditional ie 6,7,and 8 stylesheet directly in my feature?

Comment: When you say "in my feature" are you referring to module produced by the features module or something else?

Comment: yes, a module built using the features module www.drupal.org/project/features

Comment: Features are just like a online repository where u can move backward and forth. May i know why u need to use stylesheets in features? Or r u talking about any thing that has been created in features?